# Tailwind - How Flex-No-Shrink and Flex-Wrap Work

Tags: css, flexbox, tailwind-css

I have two issues,

1. "Flex-no-shrink" does not work when I specify width(say w-1/5)... Isn't this possible? As soon as when I specify some width on a div, all flex properties seem to be not working.  (My goal here is since it's a sidebar div, I want the width to remain the same in all sections of my app, however in some sections my sidebar content is shorter, therefore I end up having a sidebar with different width across my site)
2. Similar problem exists for my "flex-wrap" as well. If I dont specify the width of the child divs, flex wrap works as I resize my browser.  When I specify width, divs will start shrinking without jumping to bottom.

```
<div class="mt-2 mb-5 pl-4">
     <div class="flex w-full">
         <div class="flex-no-shrink w-1/5 bg-white border-sidebarborder border rounded shadow my-2 pt-3 px-2">
             @yield('sidebarmenu')
         </div>

         <div class="bg-white m-2 border border-contentborder rounded shadow border-sidebarborder w-full">
             @yield ('content')
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks.
Sidebar is structured as below;

```
<ul class="sidebar-ul">
    <label class="sidebarheader">Management </label>
    <li class="sidebar-li sidebar-li:hover"> <a class="sidebar-a sidebar-a:hover"> Item  </a> </li>
</ul>
```

Since i use this through-out the site, i took it out to app.scss, style is as below;

```css
.sidebarheader {
    background-color: #d5e5ef;
    @apply  block py-2 mb-1 px-2 text-sm capitalize;
}
.sidebar-li {
    @apply pb-1 px-3;
}
.sidebar-li:hover {
background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

.sidebar-a {
    color:navy;
    font-size:13px;
    @apply no-underline;
}

.sidebar-a:hover {
    color: #3f71b1;
    @apply underline;
}

.sidebar-ul {
    @apply list-reset w-full pb-6 ;
}
```

Comment: Right now your question can only be answered by people with CSS knowledge **and** tailwind knowledge. If you provide a [***runnable***](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) [mcve], including required resources and allowing inspection, you'll make your question answerable by anyone with CSS knowledge regardless of familiarity with tailwind, which is a significantly larger pool.

Comment: you will probably have to post your sidebarmenu @content code aswell - this might have some styling on that they may causing a issue

Comment: @CodeBoyCode I just updated the post with my sidebar styling and structure. Content section is different on every page--- would content can affect sidebar div like hat ? On some pages, i have headings, forms etc....

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you cannot use flex-no-shrink with a % width class such as:

```
'1/2': '50%',
'1/3': '33.33333%',
'2/3': '66.66667%',
'1/4': '25%',
'3/4': '75%',
'1/5': '20%',
'2/5': '40%',
'3/5': '60%',
'4/5': '80%',
'1/6': '16.66667%',
'5/6': '83.33333%',
```

I'd recommend sticking with a fixed size, or alternatively adding custom css class and using `calc()`

Sorry that I don't have better news, but using a percentage class will always result in scaling as it is a % of the `vw`